# Overwriting archive-product.php but why not allowing me to edit?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've copied `archive-product.php` over to my `theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

I've also tried replacing `woocommerce_content()` in `woocommerce.php` with the obvious found online.

Which then seems to muck up my shop page by moving the sidebar below my products and effecting the footer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, not being allowed to edit results from rights problems. Make sure you have the right permissions set for your theme files

Maybe take a look a this: [wordpress: changing file permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)